# Missing parameter username error in Zap API

Tags: python-3.x, owasp, zap

I have been running Zap authenticated scans using a Zest login script, but auth have broken after I updated Zap docker image - seems like it's due to a change in API.

Here is the output I get:

```
5309955 [ZAP-ProxyThread-3963] INFO org.parosproxy.paros.control.Control  - New session file created
zap       | 5313051 [ZAP-ProxyThread-3971] INFO org.zaproxy.zap.authentication.ScriptBasedAuthenticationMethodType  - Loaded script for API:login.zst
zap       | 5313633 [ZAP-ProxyThread-3975] WARN org.zaproxy.zap.extension.api.API  - Bad request to API endpoint [/JSON/users/action/setAuthenticationCredentials/] from [10.254.0.6]:
zap       | Missing Parameter (missing_parameter) : Username
```

And this is how I supply auth parameters:

```
authmethod_params = ('scriptName=' + auth_script_name + '&'
                     'Submission Form URL={0}/{1}&'
                     'Username field=username&'
                     'Password field=password&'
                     'Target URL=http://www.example.com/login')
 # setup authentication
 auth = zap.authentication
 auth.set_authentication_method(
 contextid=context_id,
 authmethodname=auth_method_name,
 authmethodconfigparams=authmethod_params)
```

For some reason, the API does not recognize the username parameter and, subsequently, login fails. Can you please provide a **current** example of how to pass login parameters for script-based auth to Zap API?

Many thanks

Comment: Current example: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-api-python/blob/master/src/examples/zap_example_api_script.py

Comment: The same syntax I have been using, the problem must be somewhere else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason: the auth broke on a new user because I did not update base 64-encoded credentials in the request.

Comment: Thanks for following up.